# Quadratic programming problem involving permutation matrices

Tags: algorithms, optimization, permutations, approximation-algorithms

Does anyone know a good algorithm for quickly finding an approximate solution to the following problem?

Given two square matrices $A$ and $B$, minimize $\| P A P^\top - B \|$ over all permutation matrices $P$.

I have heard that there are several types of algorithms for these kinds of problems, like iterative improvement, simulated annealing, tabu search, genetic algorithms, evolution strategies, ant algorithms, and scatter search. I am looking for existing software.

Comment: This question may be better suited to scicomp.stackexchange.com since you are looking for a particular piece of software.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, even though it is on-topic here, because it was cross-posted on [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10415/4274).  Go there to answer or see what others have suggested.